# Google Cloud Storage Bucket can't transfer data in

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, bucket, identity-management

I am granted with a customized role with below permissions

- bigquery.connections.delegate
- bigquery.savedqueries.get
- bigquery.savedqueries.list
- logging.views.access
- storage.buckets.get
- storage.buckets.getIamPolicy
- storage.buckets.list
- storage.multipartUploads.abort
- storage.multipartUploads.create
- storage.multipartUploads.list
- storage.multipartUploads.listParts
- storage.objects.create
- storage.objects.get
- storage.objects.list

When I try to create a transfer job to bring data into a bucket/folder that I created, [image: this error pops]

this error pops up (Failed to obtain the location of the GCS bucket contributed Additional details: project-720965328418@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).)

However, this project doesn't have any service account (I can view this because I have a different account with the owner privilege)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are looking in the wrong place. Go to **IAM & Admin -> IAM** which is a different screen. Then, click the checkbox located in the top right **Include Google-managed role grants**. If the service account still does not show, click the **GRANT ACCESS** button and enter the email address.